# Connecting two Models to create a dropdown

Tags: django

I want to know how I can connect 2 models to create a dropdown which is dependent on each other.

As of writing, these are my models for the videos:

```
class AMLVideo(models.Model):

    LANGUAGE = (
        ('LAN', 'Language'),
        ('FR', 'French'),
        ('EN', 'English'),
        ('HIN', 'Hindi'),
        ('SPA', 'Spanish'),
        ('GER', 'German'),
    )

    LEVEL = (
        ('BEG', 'Beginner'),
        ('INT', 'Intermediary'),
        ('ADV', 'Advanced'),
    )

    CATEGORY = (
        ('ANI', 'Animal'),
        ('ENV', 'Environmental'),
        ('MOR', 'Moral'),
        ('FOLK', 'Folktales'),
        ('ADN', 'Adventure'),
        ('POE', 'Poems'),
        ('FUN', 'Funny'),
    )
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, default='Enter-Slug-Here')
    level = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=LEVEL, default='level', blank=True)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=LANGUAGE, default='language', blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CATEGORY, default='category', blank=True)
    video = EmbedVideoField(verbose_name='Videos',
                        help_text='URL of Video')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "video"
        verbose_name_plural = "videos"
```

This is the views which already shows the videos using an iframe

```
def home(request):
    videos = AMLVideo.objects.all()

    # Get category from filter
    category = request.GET.get('category', '')
    if category:
        videos = videos.filter(
            category__exact=category
        )

    # Get language from filter
    language = request.GET.get('language', '')
    if language:
        videos = videos.filter(
            language__exact=language
        )

    # Get level from filter
    level = request.GET.get('level', '')
    if level:
        videos = videos.filter(
            level__exact=level
        )

    videos = videos.order_by("-category", "-language", "-level")

    context = {'videos': videos}
    return render (request, 'home.html', context)
```

Now for the dropdown, I'm not quite sure how to show it using a model or a form on the template.

I was hoping that if a user choses something from the dropdown, the videos that would be shown is based on the dropdown that the user chose.

Is this possible?

Comment: You'll need to use some JavaScript and Ajax so when the first dropdown is selected you make a database call and get the options of the second dropdown

Comment: are those the only way of doing it? I'm not comfortable with js and ajax.

Comment: Alternative would be to make it 2 stage.  Having made first model selection submit the form to get the options for the second

Comment: What form are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle that by using Django Form, which you can render in the template, keep filter value to send to the view. Like so:

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class AMLVideoFilterForm(forms.Form):
    LANGUAGE = (
        ('LAN', 'Language'),
        ('FR', 'French'),
        ('EN', 'English'),
        ('HIN', 'Hindi'),
        ('SPA', 'Spanish'),
        ('GER', 'German'),
    )

    LEVEL = (
        ('BEG', 'Beginner'),
        ('INT', 'Intermediary'),
        ('ADV', 'Advanced'),
    )

    CATEGORY = (
        ('ANI', 'Animal'),
        ('ENV', 'Environmental'),
        ('MOR', 'Moral'),
        ('FOLK', 'Folktales'),
        ('ADN', 'Adventure'),
        ('POE', 'Poems'),
        ('FUN', 'Funny'),
    )

    language = forms.ChoiceField(choices=LANGUAGE, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange' : "this.form.submit()"}))
    level = forms.ChoiceField(choices=LEVEL, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange' : "this.form.submit()"}))
    category = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CATEGORY, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange' : "this.form.submit()"}))
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    filter_form = AMLVideoFilterForm(request.GET)
    videos = AMLVideo.objects.all()

    # Get category from filter
    category = filter_form.data.get('category')
    if category:
        videos = videos.filter(
            category__exact=category
        )

    # Get language from filter
    language = filter_form.data.get('language')
    if language:
        videos = videos.filter(
            language__exact=language
        )

    # Get level from filter
    level = filter_form.data.get('level')
    if level:
        videos = videos.filter(
            level__exact=level
        )

    videos = videos.order_by("-category", "-language", "-level")

    context = {'videos': videos, 'filter_form': filter_form}
    return render (request, 'home.html', context)
```

**home.html**

```
<body>
...
    <form method="GET">
        {{ filter_form }}
    </form>

    {% for video in videos %}
        <p>Render your video here</p>
    {% endfor %}
...
</body>
```

Then whenever you change filter choices, it will submit the form in GET method. In the view, you'll have to get filters in form data to filter data. About the widgets, you have to add onchange event so that whenever user change the dropdown value, it will submit the form to filter the data again. This is an alternative way to handle without using JavaScript or jQuery.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried what you did but this is the output https://highcenburg.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/output.png

Comment: you could add required=False into filter form. e.g: `language = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, choices=LANGUAGE, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange' : "this.form.submit()"}))`

Comment: Seem like we already talk about this before lol.. but at that time you want to set dynamic choices right? Oh btw.. I also recommend you to use `django-filter` if you're familiar with Django stuff.

Comment: There's no button https://highcenburg.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/no-button.png and once the user chooses a category, language or level, the videos should change;

Comment: Yeah, should make it work in this post. I was confused on previous question. So is there any select element on the html source? Please inspect the page to see is there any select element? It suppose to be 3 select elements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199824/discussion-between-highcenburg-and-toan-quoc-ho).